# Latest TOR Browser Bundle update fails to open privacy/security settings tab, strange behavior

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, debian, add-on, settings

I've installed the latest TOR Browser Bundle 9.5.4 ESR for Debian Linux and it doesn't allow access to the privacy/security settings tab any more. If you open Menu > Preferences, the following tabs/pages won't open any more:

```
about:preferences#home
about:preferences#search
about:preferences#privacy
about:preferences#tor
```

Can anyone reproduce this behavior? Also, since the most recent update, TOR quietly keeps installing a package that keeps popping up as a permanent process `debian-tor` that cannot be killed/keeps restarting. Also, the browser suffers from extreme memory leaks and CPU/RAM loads. Plus, the addon shortcuts (uBlock Origin, HTTPS Everywhere, NoScript) are no longer displayed in the menu bar and, in particular, NoScript options are no longer editable (a loading animation will appear indefinitely).

It feels like TOR is completely getting out of control...

Answer (score 0):

> If you open Menu > Preferences, the following tabs/pages won't open any more [...]

Those links work fine for me on Linux with Tor Browser 9.5.4. Maybe try re-installing the browser, otherwise maybe make a bug report.

> Also, since the most recent update, TOR quietly keeps installing a package that keeps popping up as a permanent process debian-tor that cannot be killed/keeps restarting.

This is because you installed the `tor` package from an apt repository (either you ran `apt install tor`, or you installed something that depends on tor like OnionShare). You can run `apt remove tor` to uninstall it.

> Plus, the addon shortcuts (uBlock Origin, HTTPS Everywhere, NoScript) are no longer displayed in the menu bar

They were removed from the menu bar to prevent people from making changes that could harm their anonymity. If you want to put these icons on your menu bar, right-click the menu bar and choose "Customize".

Comment: I have the same issues. May I ask what qualifies you to make these statements, are you a TOR browser developer? Both the Linux and Android version seem poisoned (lacking a better expression for this erratic behavior). I also cannot open the preferences anymore. The addon icons won't show up unless I intentionally crash TOR browser processes such as `tor` or `Web Content
` 3-4 times - then suddenly they reappear. Also, what possible reason is there for `firefox.real` consuming 60-70% CPU constantly?

Comment: @davidra contact me in comments to my answer - looks like you've been hit with a fake distro

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a fake executable - it's not a paranoia, I've helped some years ago on this very website to the person who has got a fake `tor.exe` file in the distribution. Let's run through a checklist:

1. What is the checksum and the URL for your source website's HTTPS certificate?
2. Have you performed a checksum verification for a binary/distro you've downloaded?
3. How exactly have you reached the site you've got the distribution from?